# U-Boot: Compilation Error When Trying to include TPM Header Files

Tags: compiler-errors, u-boot

I am trying to make use of a couple of TPM V2 APIs in the FIT Image Signature verification flow. For the same, I have tried including the TPM header files in the following manner:
I'm working with the Master Branch.

```
diff --git a/common/image-fit-sig.c b/common/image-fit-sig.c
index 63e5423c92..529da516cc 100644
--- a/common/image-fit-sig.c
+++ b/common/image-fit-sig.c
@@ -18,6 +18,9 @@ DECLARE_GLOBAL_DATA_PTR;
 #include <u-boot/rsa.h>
 #include <u-boot/hash-checksum.h>
 
+#include <tpm-common.h>
+#include <tpm-v2.h>
+
 #define IMAGE_MAX_HASHED_NODES         100
 
 /**
```

However, on compiling I get the following error:

```
$ make -j$(nproc) CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- all
UPD     include/generated/timestamp_autogenerated.h
  CFGCHK  u-boot.cfg
  HOSTCC  tools/aisimage.o
  HOSTCC  tools/atmelimage.o
  HOSTCC  tools/fit_image.o
  HOSTCC  tools/fit_common.o
  HOSTCC  tools/image-host.o
  HOSTCC  tools/common/image-fit.o
  HOSTCC  tools/image-sig-host.o
  HOSTCC  tools/common/image-fit-sig.o
  HOSTCC  tools/common/image-cipher.o
In file included from ./tools/../common/image-fit-sig.c:21,
                 from tools/common/image-fit-sig.c:1:
include/tpm-common.h:66:2: error: unknown type name ‘u8’
   66 |  u8 buf[TPM_DEV_BUFSIZE + sizeof(u8)];  /* Max buffer size + addr */
      |  ^~
include/tpm-common.h:66:34: error: ‘u8’ undeclared here (not in a function)
   66 |  u8 buf[TPM_DEV_BUFSIZE + sizeof(u8)];  /* Max buffer size + addr */
      |                                  ^~
include/tpm-common.h:131:44: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
  131 |  int (*send)(struct udevice *dev, const u8 *sendbuf, size_t send_size);
      |                                            ^
include/tpm-common.h:144:35: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘u8’
  144 |  int (*recv)(struct udevice *dev, u8 *recvbuf, size_t max_size);
      |                                   ^~
include/tpm-common.h:173:44: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
  173 |  int (*xfer)(struct udevice *dev, const u8 *sendbuf, size_t send_size,
      |                                            ^
include/tpm-common.h:259:44: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
  259 | int tpm_xfer(struct udevice *dev, const u8 *sendbuf, size_t send_size,
      |                                            ^
In file included from ./tools/../common/image-fit-sig.c:22,
                 from tools/common/image-fit-sig.c:1:
include/tpm-v2.h:117:2: error: unknown type name ‘u16’
  117 |  u16 hash;
      |  ^~~
include/tpm-v2.h:118:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘u8’
  118 |  u8 size_of_select;
      |  ^~
include/tpm-v2.h:120:3: error: conflicting types for ‘__packed’
  120 | } __packed;
      |   ^~~~~~~~
include/tpm-v2.h:113:3: note: previous declaration of ‘__packed’ was here
  113 | } __packed;
      |   ^~~~~~~~
include/tpm-v2.h:126:3: error: conflicting types for ‘__packed’
  126 | } __packed;
      |   ^~~~~~~~
include/tpm-v2.h:113:3: note: previous declaration of ‘__packed’ was here
  113 | } __packed;
      |   ^~~~~~~~
include/tpm-v2.h:132:3: error: conflicting types for ‘__packed’
  132 | } __packed;
      |   ^~~~~~~~
include/tpm-v2.h:113:3: note: previous declaration of ‘__packed’ was here
  113 | } __packed;
      |   ^~~~~~~~
include/tpm-v2.h:142:3: error: conflicting types for ‘__packed’
  142 | } __packed;
      |   ^~~~~~~~
include/tpm-v2.h:113:3: note: previous declaration of ‘__packed’ was here
  113 | } __packed;
      |   ^~~~~~~~
include/tpm-v2.h:148:3: error: conflicting types for ‘__packed’
  148 | } __packed;
      |   ^~~~~~~~
include/tpm-v2.h:113:3: note: previous declaration of ‘__packed’ was here
  113 | } __packed;
      |   ^~~~~~~~
include/tpm-v2.h:162:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘u8’
  162 |  u8 digest[TPM2_SHA1_DIGEST_SIZE];
      |  ^~
include/tpm-v2.h:165:3: error: conflicting types for ‘__packed’
  165 | } __packed;
      |   ^~~~~~~~
include/tpm-v2.h:113:3: note: previous declaration of ‘__packed’ was here
  113 | } __packed;
      |   ^~~~~~~~
include/tpm-v2.h:171:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘u8’
  171 |  u8 sha1[TPM2_SHA1_DIGEST_SIZE];
      |  ^~
include/tpm-v2.h:176:3: error: conflicting types for ‘__packed’
  176 | } __packed;
      |   ^~~~~~~~
include/tpm-v2.h:113:3: note: previous declaration of ‘__packed’ was here
  113 | } __packed;
      |   ^~~~~~~~
include/tpm-v2.h:185:2: error: unknown type name ‘u16’
  185 |  u16 hash_alg;
      |  ^~~
include/tpm-v2.h:187:3: error: conflicting types for ‘__packed’
  187 | } __packed;
      |   ^~~~~~~~
include/tpm-v2.h:113:3: note: previous declaration of ‘__packed’ was here
  113 | } __packed;
      |   ^~~~~~~~
include/tpm-v2.h:198:3: error: conflicting types for ‘__packed’
  198 | } __packed;
      |   ^~~~~~~~
include/tpm-v2.h:113:3: note: previous declaration of ‘__packed’ was here
  113 | } __packed;
      |   ^~~~~~~~
include/tpm-v2.h:214:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘u8’
  214 |  u8 event[];
      |  ^~
include/tpm-v2.h:215:3: error: conflicting types for ‘__packed’
  215 | } __packed;
      |   ^~~~~~~~
include/tpm-v2.h:113:3: note: previous declaration of ‘__packed’ was here
  113 | } __packed;
      |   ^~~~~~~~
include/tpm-v2.h:469:14: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
  469 |     const u8 *nv_policy, size_t nv_policy_size);
      |              ^
include/tpm-v2.h:483:16: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
  483 |       const u8 *digest, u32 digest_len);
      |                ^
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.host:112: tools/common/image-fit-sig.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [Makefile:1804: tools] Error 2
```

It seems that the 'u8' and 'u16' can be circumvented by adding typedefs, however I'm not sure how files like lib/tpm-v2.c and lib/tpm_api.c include these headers without compilation error.

Please let me know if I'm missing something trivial in the above inclusions or how can I include the tpm-v2 header files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some files such as `common/image-fit-sig.c` are shared between both U-Boot itself and our runs-on-host tools.  In those cases, when adding new code / headers, extra care needs to be taken.  You'll need to add those headers under the non-`USE_HOSTCC` case at the top of the file and your code will need to be behind and #ifdef as well.